# How to add onmouseover attribute to <OPTION></OPTION> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to add onmouseover to the option tag to display the text value. Can someone please help me on this?

```
    var opt;

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i) 
    {
        var tempResult=new Array();
        tempResult=response[i].split('|');

        opt = document.createElement("OPTION");
        opt.text = tempResult[1];
        opt.value= tempResult[0];
        opt.title = tempResult[2];
        opt.attributes.add

        matchList.options.add(opt);
    }
```

Comment: text value will be display by default, why onmouseover?

Comment: See [*MDN: addEventListener*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). A mouseover event for option elements only makes sense in a multi-select. Note that it's not accessible since keyboard navigation won't trigger a mouseover, or maybe there's an [*ARIA attribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/WAI-ARIA_basics) for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i) 
{
    var tempResult=new Array();
    tempResult=response[i].split('|');

    var opt = document.createElement("OPTION");
    opt.text = tempResult[1];
    opt.value= tempResult[0];
    opt.title = tempResult[2];
    opt.setAttribute('onmouseover', `alert("mouseover")`);

    matchList.options.add(opt);
}
```

I would recommend you learn functions and event listeners, instead. It can be much more organized than inline JavaScript.